# Facebook API get events CREATED BY friends

Tags: events, api, facebook

I am developing facebook app which needs to retrieve events created by some of my friends.
Standard SQL query would look like this:

```
NSString *fql1 = @"SELECT "
 @"eid, name, tagline, id, pic_small,host, description, start_time, creator "
 @"FROM "
 @"event "
 @"WHERE "
 @"creator = 1111111111 OR creator = 2222222222 OR creator = 333333333";
```

Facebook allows only to filter tables by indexed fields (which is eid in this table). I assume I could to construct multiquery. Anyone could help with it? I spent some time googling it with no look. I need only one query so learning whole fbl for this has no sense for me at the moment.

BTW: there is a function events.get - you can filter by uid (documentation says):

> parameter: uid - Filters by events associated with a
>   user with this uid.

**ASSOCIATED In what sense**? are those creator's uids?, invited, attending or maybe? Why facebook documentation is so frustrating?
When I try events.get with uid parameter it returns result with different creators ids than uid parameter. 
Graph API function: `uid/events` returns events user has been invited to, attended or other status but NOT necessarily  created by him.

What am I missing here? I granted necessary permissions to my application, it connects, gets friend's event lists but not the events I want.

Seems so simple but I con not find straight-forward solution.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Multiquery is just a fancy name to run many usual fql queries in one request, they won't give you anything new. If you don't have event ids then you can't search by creator field with FQL. You best bet would be probably exploring `events.get` but I have no idea what it returns either.

Comment: When I requested events.get with param uid I got some events but none of them has not been created by uid. What Exactly this method returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    eid, name, tagline, pic_small,host, description, start_time, creator 
FROM 
    event 
WHERE 
    eid IN (
        SELECT 
            eid 
        FROM 
            event_member 
        WHERE 
            uid=111 OR uid=222) AND 
    (creator=111 OR creator=222)
```

Basically this says get the events user 111 or 222 is a member of and of those, only return the ones they've created. Because eid is an indexable field, FQL is okay with this, and is happy to do the additional (creator=111) trimming for you.

Comment: This looks very promissing. However - I get: The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 602.). What does this error means? Am I messing somewhere with request params or query is not allowed?

Comment: Sorry id is not a valid field, it's eid for the event table. I'll edit the query to fix this.

Comment: Yep. I did not pay attention as I know there is nid column in event table. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event. Thank You. Error is gone, I am getting responce. However the is 0 results and I know there should be some.... hmmm .. I can not vote for this answer yet til I check it out.

Comment: Sorry. Your answer is perfect. I messed up something with creator ids. Thanks a lot. I learnt much out of your example, specifically that you can still narrow facebook results by non-indexed fields as long as you join it with AND after indexable filter.